# How to display a javascript string with style

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I set a paragraph element to a javascript variable with innerHTML, the paragraph element is displayed without any CSS of its divs. I am also using bootstrap.

I have tried applying style to the paragraph itself, but it is not registered/displayed with the javascript variable.

Here is the HTML with the bootstrap styling and paragraph element

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">        
    <!-- small box -->
    <div class="small-box bg-green">       

        <div class="inner">

            <h3><p font="38px" id="bounce_rate"></p></h3>
            <p>Bounce Rate</p>

        </div>

        <div class="icon">

            <i class="ion ion-stats-bars"></i>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS that sets the variable using innerHTML

```
var bounce_rate = document.getElementById('bounce_rate');

// response.result["values"][0][0] is from JSON and works as intended
bounce_rate.innerText = response.result["values"][0][0];
```

I expected the styling tags applied to the paragraph element to be applied to the javascript string. The string is displayed, it just does not have styling.

Comment: But..., but...  you are using `innerText`!?

Comment: There is no legitimate `font` attribute in html

Comment: Why not use the h3 tag directly instead of introducing p tag in it? nevertheless there's nothing like font attribute like @charliefl pointed out ...its font tag

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A heading element may not contain a paragraph element

Comment: @charlietfl, following Ethan Vu's suggestion, I am now using font-size which fixes my problem

Comment: @LegendOfPi well actually you are using `style` attribute with style values

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, @charlietfl, but what is the difference?

Comment: Look at the `=` and the quotes. Values are in the quotes and the *attribute* precedes the `=`

Comment: Ok, I am aware of that, but thought I was missing something else, regardless, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element does not have a 'font' attribute, so if your intend is to give the `<p>` element a font-size, the styling should be like this:

```
<h3><p style="font-size:38px" id="bounce_rate"></p></h3>
```

Additionally, nesting a paragraph text inside a heading text is not the right convention. If you wish to have a specific text inside `<h3>` tag to have a font-size of 38px, use `<span>` tag instead:

```
<h3><span style="font-size:38px" id="bounce_rate"></span></h3>
```

Comment: It should not and that HTML is invalid. A heading element may not contain a paragraph element

Comment: Ok, @Rob, that explains why the h3 wasn't working as I intended, but with Ethan Vu's styling, I still get the effect I intended

Comment: @SandeepRanjan Your comment doesn't make sense but the HTML is thoroughly invalid.

Comment: @SandeepRanjan Well, you are just repeating what I already said. Why you addressed that to me makes no sense at all.

Comment: @LegendOfPi You accepted an answer that "works" but it won't work when you fix your HTML. You are going to fix your HTML...aren't you?

Comment: Yes, of course, @Rob, although I didn't copy and paste the post it led me to get the correct result. Now I am using this: <h3 id="bounce_rate"></h3> (sorry for formatting) to display my variable, as per your advice. Since the post helped me find an answer, and a comment to it solved even more problems, I accepted it. I haven't used Stack Overflow much before, so please tell me if it did something incorrectly.

Comment: LegenOfPi your welcome dude, and thank you for pointing out  @Rob, i updated the answer